# MySQL - Adding a string to a text column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add a text string to certain columns. This is a query I've tried, it failed miserably though, but it explains what I want to do.

```
SET @NAME = (Select name from item_template where itemset = 801);
SET @NEWNAME = ('|cFFFF0000'+@NAME);
Update item_template set name = @NEWNAME where itemset = 801;
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
update item_template set name = concat('|cFFFF0000',name) where itemset = 801;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @NEWNAME = ('|cFFFF0000'+@NAME);
```

use concat

```
SET @NEWNAME := CONCAT('|cFFFF0000',@NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Update item_template
set name = (select * from (select concat('|cFFFF0000', name) 
                           from item_template
                           where itemset = 801) x
           ) 
where itemset = 801;
```

or even shorter

```
Update item_template
set name = concat('|cFFFF0000', name) 
where itemset = 801;
```